# Rendering controller action in Yii layout

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to Yii and I'm trying to make an application where on every page I'll have some top rated news. My question is: how can you call a controller action in a layout file? In .Net MVC there is a fine function, where in the layout you can call Html.RenderAction("TopRated", "News"). Here in the News controller you call the TopRated action. The action then renders some partial view.

How can I do this in Yii?

Comment: [This](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/543/yii-hmvc/) is how Yii implements [_HMVC_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Well, not good but better than nothing. Anyway, questions like this should always be asked on providers support page.

Comment: Yii is not .net, so things go differently here. You are probably looking for a [widget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.create#widget).

Comment: As I said, I'm new to Yii. I mentioned .Net, because I think it has better approach to this. Widget will work, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a widget and include it in your main layout. Not include it on every single view.

Comment: Widget will work, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can place that function in the main controller.php, in the components folder.

```
public function getTopRatedNews() {
    // 
}
```

As the other controllers extend from that base controller, you can simply call this from the view:

```
$news = $this->getTopRatedNews();
```